# How to only get Year as part of date / datetime in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, date

When I create a date type in SQL, the result will come out like this `2012-2-1 Monday 00:00:00`

However, I only want the year.

How can I get this?

Comment: `select Year(yourColumn) from yourTable;`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make an numeric field with just the year, or use the YEAR() function.

Answer (score 3):

datetime, includes date and time, "date" just includes date formats.

```
select datepart(year,getdate())
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this query to get current year.

```
select year(now());
```

Answer (score 2):

Could you use the following?:

```
SELECT * 
FROM
table_name
WHERE CONVERT(DATE, column_name) >= '2017-01-01'
AND
CONVERT (DATE, column_name) <= '2017-03-31';
```

But, you will probably only have to use the **CONVERT** part, as the above query gets you data between 2 specific dates.

It should just be the '**DATE**' part that is causing the problems, along with how you inserted the data. If you inserted the dates in the format of '**YYYY-MM-DD**', it should work properly.

Answer (score 0):

Not clear, do you want to just select the year? 
if you are using mysql you can do something like

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(<your field name>, '%Y') FROM <your table name> WHERE 1
```